# ng-options not behaving as expected,as documented?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

No matter what I try, the ID is always passed as the value. I want the Genre.label(string) as the value...

I am trying to get my head around ng-options, i read the docs, and the examples seem straight forward, however I am getting differet results than expected.

my model for Books is

```
Book: {
    title: string,
    genre: string,
    description: string
}
```

and my model for Genre is

```
Genre: {
    label: string
    description: string
}
```

then when I use `ng-init="getGenres()"` to pull genres into my scope, I EXPECT using

```
ng-options="genre.label for genre in genres track by genre.label"
```

will use the LABEL for each iteration and populate the option value with the LABEL and as a matter of fact - Inspect Element does show that - it looks like this:

```
<option label="Sci-fi" value="Sci-fi">Sci-fi</option>
```

My DATA however ends up looking like this:

```
_id : 5a2f...5691
genre : "5a2f552765226c3018be9878"
title : "Blah Blah"
```

Here is the form in context:

```
<form ng-submit="addBook()" ng-init="getGenres()" >
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="book.title" placeholder="Title" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>Genre</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="book.genre"
                ng-options="genre.label for genre in genres track by genre.label" >
            <option value="">-- choose genre --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the COLTROLLERs getGenres:

```
// get genres
$scope.getGenres = function() {
    $http.get('/api/genres')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.genres = response;
    });
}
```

it returns:

```
[{
    "_id": "5a2f5.....a065b",
    "label": "Sci-fi",
    "description": "Dealing with subject matter that combines fictional worlds and science, both real and theoretical."
}, {
    "_id": "5a2f5.....9877",
    "label": "Romance",
    "description": "Topics with amorous overtone, undertones and toneless rantings. Matters of the heart. Emotional folly and frolic."
}, {
    "_id": "5a2f5.....9878",
    "label": "Suspense",
    "description": "Events dealing with an arousal of anticipation and dread, mostly in equal parts."
}, {
    "_id": "5a2f5.....9879",
    "label": "Gobbeldegook",
    "description": "nonsensical gibberish. blather, post-moderistic drivel."
}, {
    "_id": "5a2f5.....987a",
    "label": "Drama",
    "description": "Drama Drama Drama Drama Drama Drama Drama"
}, {
    "_id": "5a2f5.....987b",
    "label": "NonFiction",
    "description": "Real life crap. No fakery or literary license, this is REAL!"
}]
```

Any help is much appreciated
-cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use like this:

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="book.genre"
            ng-options="genre.label  as genre.label for genre in genres track by genre.label" >
        <option value="">-- choose genre --</option>
    </select>
```

If you don't use `genre.label  as` , the genre will be used as the model in this case.
The expression BEFORE `as`, which is `genre.label`, will be used as model value.
The expression after `as`, which is `genre.label` will be used as displayed value in options.

Comment: Oi! - perfect, now I hate to ask, but how will that look on 'edit', maybe I'll post a separate Q - because ive got it in a separate form... thank a bunch.

Comment: actually...removing the "track by genre.label" fixed my edit problem, as the docs caution using "as" and "track by" in one expression. Thanks again Mavlarn